# Wrong keyboard strokes sent to serial in putty

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

I am attempting to communicate to a device i have via the onboard rx/tx solder points i found on the board. I am doing this via an arduino uno.

The problem i am having is that when i connect to it via serial (baud 115200) i get the correct output from the device but any key i press seems to come up as a random character. Is there a setting that i need to change in putty? What am i missing?

The following screenshot is just holding down the "h" key.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have probably tried already but other baud rates?
9600, 1200, 2400, 57600

Seems like 8,N,1 is common?
8 DATA, No parity, and 1 STOP bit

Maybe helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997108/what-does-putty-send-when-i-press-enter-key

Try changing what the Enter key does under the Terminal Keyboard setting might not be available in putty can't remember.

Try typing ESC[20h in putty after connecting to the device.

Try another terminal such as RealTerm?
https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/

Bad ground/connection?
Looks similar to what happened in this buspirate video on hidden serial ports, although his issue turned out to be wrong wires.
https://youtu.be/ey8flzU9DJg?t=343

A full series here might have something useful to debug why this is happening?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9q6Sye7WgU&list=PLRovDyowOn5GZBvMGBRxFG_UrpdfFV6t5

Just thoughts that come to mind as it looked like something I saw elsewhere, however I don't have a lot of experience in this area yet and have only tampered with basics with the bus pirate, sorry in advanced if im not helping...